# Adding objects per each JSON data record

Tags: javascript, json

How do I add new elements (by this I mean planets) to the below stellar system in the code snippet, based on JSON data such as this:

```
        [{
           "rowid": 1,
           "Radius size": 3 ,
           "Distance": 110 pixels,
        },
         {
           "rowid": 2,
           "Size": 2.5,
           "Distance": 120 pixels,
        }]
```

Each row ID is its own planet with its own size and position. The distance is of course based on the distance of the planet from the sun element, which is center of the page. The distance per planet needs to be in a different angle, otherwise they'd all line up perfectly (unrealistic). Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

```js
var ball = {};

function makeBall(spec) {
  // Create the element
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  // Set its various attributes
  ["id", "cx", "cy", "r", "class"].forEach(function(attrName) {
    if (spec.element[attrName]) {
      circle.setAttribute(attrName, spec.element[attrName]);
    }
  });
  // Add it to the sun
  document.getElementById("Sun2").appendChild(circle);
  // Remember its animation settings in `ball`
  ball[spec.element.id] = spec.animation;
}

function addObject() {
  // Create a spec to use with makeBall from the fields
  var spec = {
    element: {
      id: document.getElementById("new-id").value,
      class: document.getElementById("new-class").value,
      r: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-r").value)
    },
    animation: {
      speed: 2,
      spin: 30,
      side: 40
    }
  };
  // Some minimal validation
  if (!spec.element.id || !spec.element.r || !spec.animation.speed || !spec.animation.spin || isNaN(spec.animation.side)) {
    alert("Need all values to add a ball");
  } else if (ball[spec.element.id]) {
    alert("There is already a ball '" + spec.element.id + "'");
  } else {
    // Do it!
    makeBall(spec);
  }
}

function rotation(coorX, coorY, object) {
  object.side += (1.0 / object.speed);
  var ang = object.side * 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0;
  var r = object.spin;

  return {
    x: Math.cos(ang) * r - Math.sin(ang) * r + coorX,
    y: Math.sin(ang) * r + Math.cos(ang) * r + coorY
  };
}

function rotationball(circle) {
  var x, y, x_black, y_black, e, newpos, black;

  // We always rotate around black
  black = document.getElementById("black");
  
  // Get this circle and update its position
  e = document.getElementById(circle);
  x_black = parseFloat(black.getAttribute("cx"));
  y_black = parseFloat(black.getAttribute("cy"));
  newpos = rotation(x_black, y_black, ball[circle]);

  e.setAttribute("cx", newpos.x);
  e.setAttribute("cy", newpos.y);
}

function animate() {
  Object.keys(ball).forEach(function(id) {
    rotationball(id);
  });
}

var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: yellow;
}

.st1 {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>Add ball:
  <label>
    ID: <input type="text" id="new-id" value="newball">
  </label>
  <label>
    R: <input type="text" id="new-r" value="10">
  </label>
  <label>
    Speed: <input type="text" id="new-speed" value="1.2">
  </label>
  <label>
    Spin: <input type="text" id="new-spin" value="80">
  </label>
  <label>
    Side: <input type="text" id="new-side" value="0.0">
  </label>
  <label>
    Class: <input type="text" id="new-class" value="st1">
  </label>
  <button type="button" onclick="addObject()">
    Make Ball
  </button>
</div>

<div class="spinning">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="solly" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
    <g id="Sun2">
      <circle id="black" class="st0" cx="500" cy="300.8" r="10" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The above is code (not entirely mine), that adds new balls (planets) if it has its own ID. I just want to switch this up with the JSON dataset.

EDIT: 
Below are original examples of two records. As you can see it offers a lot more but redundant properties. All I really require from each record are the size (Planet Radius [Jupiter radii] and distance (Distance [pc]). Distance would need to be converted to pixels, size is trickier.

```
     [{
       "rowid": 1,
       "Host name": "TrES-3",
       "Number of Planets in System": 1,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 1.91,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 1.336,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": 0.994
       },
       "Distance [pc]": 228,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": 5650,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    },
     {
       "rowid": 2,
       "Host name": "UZ For",
       "Number of Planets in System": 2,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 6.3,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": null
       },
       "Distance [pc]": null,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": null,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    }]
```

Comment: Excellent question!

Comment: Looks interesting enough, hope someone can help you out here

Comment: Please educate yourself about what JSON is, and is not. It's a **string-based format** for exchanging information such as with servers. It's **not** a word referring to regular old JavaScript objects such as in your question. Please try to avoid confusing everyone including yourself with such incorrect terminology.

Comment: Alright, how should I have worded it? As I said to user2415266, I am quite new to JSON.

Comment: `"Distance": 110 pixels,` is not a valid line in a JSON object, it either has to be just a number `110` or a string `"110 pixels"`, or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple:

If you read through the HTML, you will notice that clicking the "Make Ball" button will call addObject(). So you go and check for that function in the JS code.
addObject() simply parses the values from the input fields into an object called spec, then calls makeBall(spec).

What you need to do is to provide the exact same data object spec for the makeBall function, for each of your JSON data.

```
function addObjectsFromJson(json){
    // using try catch block because JSON.parse will throw an error if the json is malformed
    try{
        var array = JSON.parse(json);
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            var planet = array[i];
            // create a spec to use with makeBall from the json
            var spec = {
                element: {
                    id: planet.rowid,
                    // you don't provide a style class in your json yet, using yellow as default
                    class: 'st0',
                    // your json must have a standard property for radius,
                    // currently you have "Radius size" (is wrong since
                    // properties cannot have spaces) and "Size"
                    r: planet["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"]
                },
                animation: {
                    speed: 2,
                    spin: 30,
                    side: planet["Distance [pc]"]
                }
            };
            makeBall(spec);
        }
    }catch(e){
        console.log('error: ' + e);
    }
}
```

I don't see a property for adding a distance in the makeBall() function though.

Handle JSON via ajax with jQuery:

```
// assuming your local server runs on port 8080
$.getJSON('localhost:8080/path/to/your/file', function (json) {
    // since we use getJSON, it is already parsed and a javascript object
    // additional parsing inside the addObjectsFromJson function is not necassary
    // and would throw an error
    addObjectsFromJson(json);
});

function addObjectsFromJson(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var planet = json[i];
        // create a spec to use with makeBall from the json
        var spec = {
            element: {
                id: planet.rowid,
                // you don't provide a style class in your json yet, using yellow as default
                class: 'st0',
                // your json must have a standard property for radius,
                // currently you have "Radius size" (is wrong since properties cannot have spaces) and "Size"
                    r: planet["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"]
                },
                animation: {
                    speed: 2,
                    spin: 30,
                    side: planet["Distance [pc]"]
        };
        makeBall(spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the function retrieve the JSON data? What if the data is really a long .json file consisting thousands of records. I took only a pair of them and rewrote it to just bare essentials so people could get the idea of it faster. As you might have guessed, I'm not too experienced with handling JSON, that's why I didn't know for instance that the properties couldn't have spaces. Should I show two records how they originally look?

Comment: Yes please. How do you provide the JSON data?

Comment: I've updated my question with two of those records per requested. Also, I provide the JSON data by retrieving the .json file that's in the same folder as the HTML page. I work on a local server.

Comment: Dirty way to use your data: copy paste all of your jsons file into the javascript, wrap it in '' and write var json = in front of it. That saves it as a string in a variable. Should be okay for local testing. The proper way would be to load it via ajax when you need it. Since the plain javascript ajax functions are pretty hard to understand I suggest checking out [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or more specific (and easier) [jQuery getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). Those will load the json file for you, and you can then use the content in the success function.

Comment: The $.getJSON is working, but I can only assume because when I implement your written code in with the snippets I posted in my question, the planets revolve very slowly whenever I "make a new ball." But I don't think you know for sure what it is I want. Namely, whenever the page is loaded, that there will be already revolving planets around the sun based on the number of records in the JSON data. Eventually there will be no need for a "Make ball" button, because they've already been made dynamically.

Comment: Of course because I didn't change the properties to thos in your json..please do a little bit thinking yourself...I edited my answer to contain the correct object properties.